# Calling a non void method with one parameter but requires two objects

Tags: java, object

So for example, starA.addstarsize(starB). Is it possible for this method to return ANOTHER new star object. And if so how would I write it. Writing it as

```
public void addsizestar(starB)
```

doesnt return a new star object and only updates starA and writing it as

```
public static star addsizestar(startB)
```

requires another parameter. I want to keep it at one input parameter if possible.

Comment: Try, you are  allowed to do that

Comment: `star starC = starA.addsizestar(starB);`, but you should be using Java naming conventions - `Star` and `addSizeStar` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a new start that is a copy of starA\, change it and return it.

```
public star addsizestar(starB)
{
    starT = new star(starA parameters); // you will create new star with the
    //size and what parameters you have
    sratT.addstarsize(starB);
    return starT;
}
```

few point: 
1. classes name starts with capital. it should be `Star` and not `star`. 
2. if you want method to return something, it cannot be void type.
3. don't make method static if you don't have to. static methods have their disadvantages

Answer (score 1):

```
public Star addsizestar(StarB b) {
    Star result = new Star();

    //your code, you can use 'b' and 'this' for work

    return result;
}
```